# Passar dois parâmetros de uma vez para a controller - Um parâmetro esta em um Input Group

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html5, asp.net

Bom dia pessoal.

Sou novo em Asp.Net e peguei um projeto pessoal para fazer, porém estou com dificuldades de passar parâmetros para a controller. Não sei como passar mais de um parâmetro por vez. Tenho um modal para alterar o tipo de acomodação de leito hospitalar. Preciso passar para a controller o código do leito e o código do novo tipo de acomodação, porém não consegui de jeito nenhum. Estou pesquisando aqui e no google há pelo manos 4 dias =/

O código do leito esta em **leito.CdLeito.ToString()**

E o código do tipo de acomodação esta em **hm.GetTipoAcomodacao().Rows[i][0].ToString()** e está em um input group

**Obs**: Tentei por Get e por Post, não consegui em nenhum. O formaction do botão salvar chama a controller, porém não envia os códigos

**Obs2**: Desculpa ai se o código estiver fora dos padrões de programação, é que realmente iniciei agora em Asp.Net. Conheço apenas C# básico.

**Obs3**: Estou aberto a qualquer sugestão de melhoria no código.

Seguem os códigos

**HTML**

```
@foreach (var unidade in hm.GetAllUnidInt())
{
    <!-- ESSE FOREACH LISTA TODAS AS UNIDADES DE INTERNAÇÃO -->

        foreach (var leito in hm.GetLeitosAtivos())
            {               
                <!-- ESSE FOREACH CARREGA TODOS OS LEITOS ATIVOS-->

                if (unidade.DescricaoUnidade.ToString() == leito.DsUnidInt.ToString())
                {

                    <!-- ESSE IF É PARA MOSTRAR O LEITO DA RESPECTIVA UNIDADE DE INTERNAÇÃO -->

                    if (@leito.StatusLeito.ToString() == "OCUPADO")
                    {
                        <!--DIV Leito Ocupado - transparente-->
                        <!--AQUI TEM UM CARD COM UM BUTTON QUE CHAMA O MODAL CASO A CONDIÇÃO SEJA A DO IF-->

                    }
                    else if (@leito.StatusLeito.ToString() == "VAGO")
                    {
                        <!--DIV Leito Vago - Verde-->
                        <!--AQUI TEM UM CARD COM UM BUTTON QUE CHAMA O MODAL CASO A CONDIÇÃO SEJA A DO ELSE IF-->


                    }
                    else if (@leito.StatusLeito.ToString() == "LIMPEZA")
                    {
                        <!--DIV Leito Em limpeza - Amarelo-->
                        <!--AQUI TEM UM CARD COM UM BUTTON QUE CHAMA O MODAL CASO A CONDIÇÃO SEJA A DO ELSE IF-->


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <!--DIV Leito Interditado - Amarelo-->
                        <!--AQUI TEM UM CARD COM UM BUTTON QUE CHAMA O MODAL CASO A CONDIÇÃO SEJA A DO ELSE-->


                    }

                    <!--Modal - Alterar acomodação do leito-->
                    <form method="post">
                        <div class="modal fade" id="@string.Concat("alteraAcomodacao", leito.CdLeito.ToString())" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar informações do leito</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <label id="leitoSelecionado" value="@leito.CdLeito.ToString()"></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">

                                        <p>Alterar o tipo de acomodação do leito</p>
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            @{
                                                <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                                                    <option selected>Selecione a nova acomodação...</option>
                                                    @for (int i = 0; i < hm.GetTipoAcomodacao().Rows.Count; i++)
                                                    {
                                                        <!-- ESSE FOR É PARA POPULAR UM DROPDOWN COM OS TIPOS DE ACOMODAÇÃO PARA O USUÁRIO SELECIONAR-->

                                                        <option value="@hm.GetTipoAcomodacao().Rows[i][0].ToString()">@hm.GetTipoAcomodacao().Rows[i][1].ToString()</option>
                                                    }

                                                </select>
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                        <br />

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancelarAlteracoesLeito">Cancelar</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-submit" formaction="@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { cdLeito = @leito.CdLeito.ToString(), novaAcomodacao = @hm.GetTipoAcomodacao().Rows[i][0].ToString() })">Salvar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>




            }

}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string cdLeito, string novaAcomodacao)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: você pode passar por *query string* na própria url da action: `/controller/Index/?cdLeito=1&novaAcomodacao=2` por exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara que coincidência rsrsr

Eu fiz exatamente o que você falou, mas antes de ver sua resposta e quando vim postar aqui que tinha conseguido, vi seu comentário rsrsr

Resolvi todo o problema com o método Get, o código ficou desse jeito:

```
<!--Modal - Alterar acomodação do leito-->
<form method="get">
    <div class="modal fade" id="@string.Concat("alteraAcomodacao", leito.CdLeito.ToString())" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar informações do leito</h5>

                    <!-- INPUT HIDDEN PARA PEGAR O CÓDIGO DO LEITO-->
                    <input type="text" value="@leito.CdLeito.ToString()" hidden name="cdLeito"/>


                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <p>Alterar o tipo de acomodação do leito</p>



                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @{
                            <select name="novaAcomodacao" class="custom-select">
                                <option>Selecione a nova acomodação...</option>
                                @for (int i = 0; i < hm.GetTipoAcomodacao().Rows.Count; i++)
                                {

                                    <option value="@hm.GetTipoAcomodacao().Rows[i][0].ToString()">@hm.GetTipoAcomodacao().Rows[i][1].ToString()</option>


                                }

                            </select>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <br />

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancelarAlteracoesLeito">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-submit">Salvar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Não acho que esse seja o caminho mais adequado a ser seguido. Além expor toda a sua entrada de dados na url, você ainda estará abrindo mão de diversos recursos e validações que o .Net pode oferecer para você.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar um input hidden para persistir o `cdLeito` e seus inputs precisam apresentar o atributo name para que os valores sejam incluídos no `FormData` e enviados à rota de destino

```
<input type="hidden" id="leitoSelecionado" name="cdLeito" value="@leito.CdLeito.ToString()"/>
```

E

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="novaAcomodacao">
```